# How to import a Java Web project inside another Java Web project?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, maven, web, module

I want to create a "module" web project which will be used in plenty of other web projects because its base code is shared among all of them, as well as some stand-alone functionalities from the module.

Let's name them `Module` project and `Consumer` project.
I'm using JSF 2 with CDI/EJB, `@Named('managedBean')` and Maven on all of them except for the `Module` project, which is not using EJB because it's not necessary (it contains only ManagedBeans and HTML views).

What I want to do is to simply import the `Module` as a Maven dependency on every `Consumer` and have them work together. In a perfect world, the `Module` should contain not only ManagedBeans and POJOs but also the JSF (HTML) files and both projects should share the same session as if it were one. The main purpose is facilitating maintenance by maintaining and updating a centralized code base which is simply imported by other Web projects; It should share the same session because the `Module` contains login functionality.

I have tried doing just that by `mvn install`ing the `Module` generating a built `jar` which is my dependency on the `Consumer` project, but neither my ManagedBeans or html views from the `Module` are being recognized when deploying the `Consumer`; my web server shows that both web projects are initialized when it deploys the `Consumer` (the views are initialized), but I was only able to access the `Consumer` pages and beans.

Building and installing the `Module` as `war` would not work when `mvn package`ing the `Consumer` because it apparently expects only `jar`s.

How can I import a Java Web project inside another Java Web project and make them work together as one?

Comment: maybe this can help you http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html